# Object jumps to the center when dragging it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, draggable

How do you use `IBeginDragHandler` and set position of drag to stay consistent and not suddenly switch to center of a GameObject?

This is my simple code to grab and object and release them in a new location. However, I realized that grabbing the object (2D) by the corners will auto-set the pointer to the center. It just feels shabby to leave the drag like that.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log ("Started dragging");

    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log ("Currently dragging");
        this.transform.position = eventData.position;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log ("Ended dragging");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an offset. Get the offset when `OnPointerDown` is called. Apply this offset back when `OnDrag` is called.

For 2D Sprite:

```
Camera mainCamera;
float zAxis = 0;
Vector3 clickOffset = Vector3.zero;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    zAxis = transform.position.z;
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    clickOffset = transform.position - mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(eventData.position.x, eventData.position.y, zAxis));
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    //Use Offset To Prevent Sprite from Jumping to where the finger is
    Vector3 tempVec = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position) + clickOffset;
    tempVec.z = zAxis; //Make sure that the z zxis never change

    transform.position = tempVec;
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{

}
```

For UI Object, the offset is still the-same solution but `ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle` should also be used.

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler
{
    public Canvas parentCanvas;
    Vector3 Offset = Vector3.zero;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 pos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, eventData.position, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out pos);
        Offset = transform.position - parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(pos);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 movePos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, eventData.position, parentCanvas.worldCamera, out movePos);
        transform.position = parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos) + Offset;
    }
}
```